# PropertyGrid scroll position not changing when set

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, propertygrid

I have a `PropertyGrid` in a Windows Forms application. Whenever its `SelectedObject` changes, it resets its `VerticalScroll` value to 0. I need it to remain where it was. The code below doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried `PerformLayout` and a bunch of other solutions with no success. Any ideas?

```
int pos = MyGrid.VerticalScroll.Value;
MyGrid.SelectedObject = SomeDifferentObject;
MyGrid.VerticalScroll.Value = pos;
```

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the [SelectedObjectsChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobjectschanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event, and repositioning there?

Comment: @schulmaster Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `VerticalScroll` property is not relevant for the PropertyGrid class. It references the internal properties of the **`VScrollBar`** control. The Scroll event is never rised.
The `VScrollBar` is child of the **`System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView`** control, a class that is not directly accessible.

You can get it anyway, casting PropertyGrid to Control or ignoring the `Browsable(false)` attribute of the PropertyGrid's `Controls` property, then find the `VScrollBar` child, store the current value then set it again after you have changed the `SelectedObject` property.
Note that this new Control can have a different number of properties than the previous, the Scroll bar will just be set where it was before.
To be more *precise*, you could get the number of properties shown before and after the new `SelectedObject` is set and perform a *relative* scroll.

Here, I find the `PropertyGridView` by its **`AccessibilityObject.Role`** which is `AccessibleRole.Table`, but you can also find it by its Text (`"PropertyGridView"`):

```
var vScroll = propertyGrid1.Controls.OfType<Control>()
    .Where(ctl => ctl.AccessibilityObject.Role == AccessibleRole.Table)
    .First().Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First();

var vScrollValue = vScroll.Value;
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = [Some Other Object];
vScroll.Value = vScrollValue;
```

If you want (as previously described), reposition the scroll bar in the same relative position, the code might become:

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

var propGrid = propertyGrid1.Controls.OfType<Control>()
    .Where(ctl => ctl.AccessibilityObject.Role == AccessibleRole.Table).First();
var totalProperties = (int)propGrid.GetType().GetField("totalProps", flags).GetValue(propGrid);

var vScroll = propGrid.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault();

float relativeScroll = 0f;
if (vScroll != null && totalProperties > 0) {
    relativeScroll = vScroll.Value / (float)totalProperties;
}

propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = [Some Other Object];

totalProperties = (int)propGrid.GetType().GetField("totalProps", flags).GetValue(propGrid);
vScroll.Value = (int)(relativeScroll * totalProperties);
```

Comment: Beautifully explained and works perfectly. Thanks much!